# Поиск всех игровых серверов по порту

Tags: c++

Наверно, вы все знаете такие игры, как Counter-Strike 1.6 и Counter-Strike Source. И знаете, что игровые сервера имеют IP:PORT(14.344.231.43:27015). Вот у меня задачка: я создал программу, и в ней есть

1. TextBox1
2. Button1

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на данную кнопку (Button1) все сервера (игровые, с указанным портом, появлялись в TextBox1?

C++

Comment: а сервера размещены в локальной сети или по всему интернету?

Comment: в сети по всему интернету

Answer (score 1):

В контре я так думаю читается список серверов, например, с какой-то определенной веб страницы по http (или по их собственному протоколу). И далее каждый из этих адресов проверяется на доступность непосредственно на самом компьютере игрока. По-другому никак. Иначе бы сервера бы ооочень долго искались (считайте нужно перебрать практически все ip от 0.0.0.1 до 255.255.255.255, да еще и по портам пройтись) А там первые сервера отображаются практически моментально. Этот список, я так думаю, пополняется каждый раз при создании нового сервера. А порты там могут быть какие угодно. В Hlds (так по-моему называется) можно в качестве порта любое число написать. Просто принято из обычно делать 27015, 27025, 27055, 27050 и т.д.

Ну а по локальной сети сервера наверное ищутся перебором каждого ip в подсети. Не так уж их там и много.
Конечно, может быть я и заблуждаюсь...

Comment: Вот как код кто нает а

Comment: А сервера Ваши или левые?

Comment: Левые Ну все какие будит искать в поиске серверов

Comment: Нужно будет разобраться с каждым типом серверов. Сразу скажу, тут все далеко не так просто, как кажется.